# Create a row of li's, give last one the classname "last" and put them all in an ul

Tags: jquery, arrays, row, html-lists

how do I create a list of li's (they look like simple boxes by using css and float left) with the certain specifications:

- 7 li's in a row
- the row is a closed ul-tag
- at the end there should be 8 rows of ul's
- the last li (the 7th) should have the class="last".

this is what i got so far, to create li's through an array (i need an array, because i need the values):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
     $.each([39, 6, 1, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], function(index, value) { 
       $("#heatmap ul").append("<li class='box' value="+value+">"+index+"</li>"); 
     });
    });
</script>
```

I appreciate your help and your time,
Nicole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd cache your selector and use the [`:nth-child(7n)`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector (every 7th child) afterwards, like this:

```
$(function () {
  var ul = $("#heatmap ul");
  $.each([39, 6, 1, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], function(index, value) { 
    ul.append("<li class='box' value="+value+">"+index+"</li>"); 
  });
  ul.children(":nth-child(7n)").addClass("last");
});
```

This prevents it finding that `<ul>` for every loop in the function.

If you float your `<li>` elements, and give them a width, and the `<ul>` 7x that width, they will float in rows of 7, like this:

```
li { float: left; width: 100px; }
ul { width: 700px }
```

Best to show a demonstration of the floating approach: [here's a quick demo of what I mean, this uses 1 `<ul>` instead of `n` `<ul>` elements, much simpler](http://jsfiddle.net/9w2zg/2/) :)

Comment: is there a way that i can create those li's AND "empty li's", which would make up a total number of 56? i could add like 46 "0"'s to the array but thats kinda annoying :)

Comment: @user309980 - At the end, or in amongst the array?

Comment: If you mean at the end of the array, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/9w2zg/3/ I just check 56 - count created, and loop that many times creating `<li>` elements before doing the `last` class, just move the class line if you don't want those blanks as part of the `class="last"` group.

Comment: wow thank you, well you asked...would it be possible amongst the array too :)

Comment: @user309980 - Not really sure how you'd pull that off, since you wouldn't know at *which* places to stick the 0's in, best to put them in the array in that case I think.

Comment: @user309980  - Welcome :)  Be sure to check an answer as accepted with the checkmark on the left when a question is resolved...helps the next person that googles and finds this get the answer quicker :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I guess?

```
var values = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ];

var $heatmap = $('#heatmap');

var currentRow = "";
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    currentRow += "<li>" + values[i] + "</li>";

    if(i % 7 == 0) {
        $heatmap.append("<ul>" + currentRow + "</ul>");
        currentRow = "";
    }
}

if(currentRow !== "") {
    $heatmap.append("<ul>" + currentRow + "</ul>");
}

$heatmap.find("ul li:last").addClass("last");
```

Outputs an `<ul>` per every 7 items in the array, and adds the `last` class to the last element in the generated `<li/>`'s

Comment: this seems to be the perfect answer but somehow doesnt work, the ul stays empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#heatmap ul li:last").addClass('last');
```

should do the trick (as jQuery can parse CSS3+ selectors)